# Removing duplicate files uploaded via html input not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, duplicates

I am currently building a file upload where I can upload one or multiple .xml files.

```
    <button mat-raised-button class="button" (click)="fileInput.click()"
        <span>Choose files</span>
        <input #fileInput type="file" multiple accept=".xml" style="display:none;" (change)="onFileInput($event)">
    </button>
```

The onFileInput method pushes those files in an array.

```
onFileInput($event) {
   Array.from($event.target.files).forEach(file => {
     this.files.push(file);
   })
   this.files = [...new Set(this.files)];
}
```

The problem is that I can upload the same file multiple times if I change the amount of files uploaded.

Case 1:
Upload files 1,2
Upload files 1,2
this.files contains files 1,2

So far so good

Case 2:
Upload files 1,2
Upload file 1
this.files contains 1,2,1
Upload file 1
this.files still contains 1,2,1
Upload file 2
this.files contains 1,2,1,2

I hope you can understand the problem and help me as I can`t find my error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Set` compares **instances** (`const a = {foo: 'bar'}; new Set([a, a])` not **values** except primitives (strings, numbers etc.). You can do it manually by comparing the files name or files size for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do it by comparing files name.

```
arr = [];
function onFileInput(e) {
  let files = e.target.files;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(files[i].name) === -1) { 
       arr.push(files[i]);
    }
  }
}
```